# Memoization in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, concurrency, memoization

I have an assembly, that computes a complicated mathematical value. This assembly is consumed by an ASP.NET application (but has no references to `System.Web`, so no access to web cache etc).

I want the results of the complicated calculation to be cached for all requests coming into the web app.

Am I right in thinking that a static field in my math class will be initialised once per `AppDomain` and that `AppDomain` will serve multiple requests, each of which will read from the static field?

For example:

```
public static class MyMath
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, decimal> results = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, decimal>();

    public static decimal ComputeValue(int input)
    {
        decimal result;

        if (!results.TryGetValue(int, out result))
        {
            result = ComputeComplicatedValue(int);
            results.TryAdd(input, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Does that example give me threadsafe cached results for multiple, unrelated, requests?

Thanks

Comment: Tovavoid ever computing the value twice for a single int, consider GetOrAdd instead of TryGet and TryAdd.

Comment: Malcom, I'm doing a similar thing with caching. What did you end up doing to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would work fine.

Static variables have a limited use in web applications just because they are shared by all threads, and need locking to access them.

In this case you *want* to share the dictionary between all threads, and the `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread safe so it takes care of the locking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ObjectCache that you can find in [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx). It basically works as ASP.NET cache, without requiring any dependency of System.Web assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache it right on the web server. The request to calculate can check if it exists on the cache or not and then call your assembly.

Otherwise yes, static math class should be shared across all the instances, but I've never been a fan of that.

Comment: This assembly is several layers deep, there is no knowledge of the fact that it is executing in a web server (which is why I specifically mentioned that).

Comment: Then you say *static math class should be shared across all the instances* - is that *should* or *will*? I need to know for certain.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear, you can use cache right on the asp code/ web application, not in your math assembly. Before calling the assembly to calculate, your web application should check the asp cache.

Comment: The instance is shared, but what about concurrency?

Comment: I don't have a reference model like: 'web server -> math'. I have a reference model like: 'web server -> UI -> business -> analysis -> computations -> math' There is NO option to check the web cache at all.

Comment: Concurrency is handled using `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

use Application object and then you have access to it in Application level

```
object someValue;
Application.Add("name", someValue);
```

and can retrieve it by this

```
Application["name"]
```

Comment: What assembly is `Application` in? I don't want to add a reference to an Application object in a Math assembly, so unless it's in System (I can't see it) this isn't going to work...